# How to link two django models in a view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to design a app where some patient details are entered, an algorithm processes these, and directs to the appropriate treatment page

I have managed to get it so patient details are entered and the user is the redirected to a view of that patient instance using the below code

But I am not sure how to in TreatmentDetailView to instead present the details of the relevant treatment rather than that patient instance.

models.py:

```
class Patient(TimeStampedModel):
    # get a unique id for each patient - could perhaps use this as slug if needed
    patient_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField("Patient Name", max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField("Age", default=0)

class Treatment(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField("Treatment Name", max_length=255)
```

views.py:

```
class PatientCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = ['name', 'sex', 'age']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('patient:detail',
                       kwargs={"slug": self.object.patient_id})

class TreatmentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Patient
    slug_field = “patient_id”
    
    def find_treatment(Patient):
        treatment_instance = runalgorithm(Patient)
        return treatment_instance
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        route='add/',
        view=views.PatientCreateView.as_view(),
        name='add'),
    
    path(
        route='<slug:slug>/',
        view=views.TreatmentDetailView.as_view(),
        name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want the patient details on this page as well as the treatment details or just the treatment details?

Comment: It would be useful to present some of the patient details on the page aswell but most important thing would be to get the treatment details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to, instead of using a DetailView, use a TemplateView and pass both objects to the context, along with a custom template.

```
class TreatmentDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "treatment.html"

def find_treatment(Patient):
    treatment_instance = runalgorithm(Patient)
    return treatment_instance

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context["patient"] = get_object_or_404(
        Patient, pk=self.kwargs['patient_id']
    )
    context"treatment"] = self.find_treatment(context["patient"])
    return context
```

Comment: Many thanks - this is a much better way. There were just a couple slight typos you may want to correct: the 'find_treatment' function needs 'self' as the initial argument or you get  number of arguments errors, and there is a missing '[' in the pennultimate line